# Set-StrictMode does not cover the whole PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I'm getting into the habit of using [Set-StrictMode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849692.aspx) for my PowerShell scripts. As a dead simple example, this works perfectly:

```powershell
param
(
    [string] $name = ""
)

Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

[string] $foo

Write-Output "Hello $name"
```

As expected, the script returns an error for `$foo` (*VariableIsUndefined*).

The problem is when I move `Set-StrictMode` to the top: in this case a couple of errors are returned, the first being unexpected since it's a *CommandNotFoundException* on the keyword `param`, where everything seems perfectly valid.

How/where can I add `Set-StrictMode` so that it covers the whole script, including the code in `param`?

Comment: Coming from Perl, I always used the 'use strict' pragma at the beginning of all my scripts, so as soon as I discovered this setting for PowerShell, I wanted to make it a regular practice for my PS scripts as well.  I'm glad at least that I found your work-around of doing the param() *before* the strict mode, but it would still be nice to understand why param() cannot follow strict mode setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you have it is the best place in a script.  The Param() statement needs to be the first statement in the script, which is why you got an error when you put the Set-Strictmode cmdlet above it.

Not sure what code in the Param() statement you want to be covered.

Comment: Yes, I've realised that `param` must be the first statement, but I was just wondering if there was a way to `Set-StrictMode` for that section too. By adding it to the top I get the usual error _CommandNotFoundException_ but, if `$name` was uninitialised and unused, I would also get the error _VariableIsUndefined_, which is the kind of check I'd like to have. Anyway, if that's not possible, never mind, it's not a big deal, I'll leave `Set-StrictMode` where it is in the example, leaving the `param` section uncovered.

Comment: Since $name is a parameter, you can mark it as mandatory like this

`Param
(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $name = ""
)`

Comment: Yes, I know the `Mandatory` attribute. However, one could provide the parameter without using it in the script. This situation would be flagged if `Set-StrictMode` could be added right at the top. Anyway, as said, it's not a big deal.